# Inconsistent error when select a column whose heading is a datetime type in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need some help on a very odd pandas problem.

I have this dataframe `df_raw` whose column index is a mix of strings and datetime type. If I run this code:

```
df = df_raw
month = pd.datetime(2018,1,1)
assert month in df.columns # this always passes
df.loc[:,month]
```

It raises a KeyError basically saying 1/1/2018 is not in the column index. But it obviously is, otherwise it won't pass the assertion.

More confusingly, if I modify the first line a little bit:

```
df = df_raw.iloc[:, 0:]
month = pd.datetime(2018,1,1)
assert month in df.columns # this always passes
df.loc[:,month]
```

It will give the correct result. But I didn't do anything different except re-selecting the entire `dataframe` (also created a copy instead of a view). 
I've been working with similar `dataframes` where the column index is a mix of `datetime` type and other types, this is the first time encountering this problem. Can some Python guru enlighten me what is this voodoo magic I'm dealing with?

Comment: I thunk you should create a deep copy of dataframe instead of `df=df_raw`  using copy module `import copy` `df=copy.deepcopy(df_raw)`

Comment: Do yoiu have same problem if use `df = df_raw.copy()` ?